# Trouble with MySQL Syntax in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table that looks roughly like this:

```
+----+-----+--------+-----------+--------+
+ ID + REG + SERIAL +     IP    + STATUS +
+----+-----+--------+-----------+--------+
+ 1  + 001 + d8dhwf + 192.168.x +   1    +
+----+-----+--------+-----------+--------+
```

And I'm trying to get the correct data from it in Python (v2.7) using the MySQLdb library. To be exact, I'm trying to just get 'REG' where 'STATUS' is 1 and 'REG' is not NULL (empty)

As such, I've attempted this:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT reg FROM table WHERE status='1' AND reg IS NOT NULL""")
```

but the last "IS NOT NULL" seems to be compelty ignored although it does not give me a syntax error.

Anyone know how to maybe do it different? Or what I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Where you say " 'REG' is not NULL (empty)" -- are the values actually NULL, or empty? (e.g. an empty string if the column is a string column)

Comment: it is an empty cell

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Comment: @khelwood varchar(255)

Comment: When you mean empty cell, you mean `NULL` cell or `" "` cell? Cell contains empty string (length = 0) will be seen as `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

If it is a `VARCHAR` column, and you want to rule out rows where the value in the column is *empty* (which is not the same as `NULL`), you should be using the condition

```
reg!=''
```

instead of

```
reg IS NOT NULL
```